# Как добавить один и тот же блок 'div' несколько раз на странице

Tags: javascript

Ситуация такова, есть следующая структура:

```
<section class="row_clear">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

В существующую структуру между вторым и третьим divом необходимо вставить специальный блок

```
<div class="clearfix hidden-lg"></div>
```

Чтоб получилось так:

```
<section class="row_clear">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="clearfix hidden-lg"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

Вроде бы ничего сложного, вот код

```
    var div       = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "clearfix hidden-lg";
    row_clear.insertBefore(div, row_clear.children[2]);
```

Но тут появилась проблема, подобных "row" блоков на странице может быть от 10 и больше.
А с помощью 'cloneNode' не хочется реализовывать, так как код будет громадным, и для каждого нового 'row' придется создавать новую переменную...

Помогите решить данную проблему... нигде не могу найти нужный ответ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C помощью [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) выбрать все `section` с классом `row_clear` и в цикле произвести `insertBefore`

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".row_clear");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "clearfix hidden-lg";
    x[i].insertBefore(div, x[i].children[2]);   
}
```

```css
.row_clear {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
.row_clear div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hidden-lg {
  padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="row_clear">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>

<hr>

<section class="row_clear">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>

<hr>

<section class="row_clear">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Просто я еще новичок в java, только учусь)

Comment: @Hochru java != javascript :) Удачного обучения)